# How can i use Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService SDK to register Facebook Channel

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger

I am trying use Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotServiceSDK to automate register bots with bot framework in facebook channel.

So, i find something like this:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService.ChannelsOperationsExtensions.Create()
```

But the first parameter is: (IChannelOperations) with description (The operation group for this extension method).

I'm not sure how to use the method.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need a [AzureBotServiceClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/399b6833e5b454dd81c4a134e105f8b85e077c3e/src/SDKs/BotService/Management.BotService/Generated/AzureBotServiceClient.cs#L86)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
      var cred = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(client, key, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
      var botClient = new AzureBotServiceClient(cred);
      botClient.SubscriptionId = subscription;

      var config = new BotChannel()
      {
        Location = "global",
        Properties = new FacebookChannel(new FacebookChannelProperties(facebookAppId, facebookAppSecret, true))
      };
      await botClient.Channels.CreateAsync(resourceGroupName, connectorName, ChannelName.FacebookChannel, config);
```

Edit:

Having tested this, I'm not convinced the library is fully functional - reading appears to work but creating resources seems to not work. I found using the rest api directly to be better. Something like this (with RestSharp):

```
      var request = new RestRequest($"resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/{botServiceName}/channels/FacebookChannel?api-version=2018-07-12", Method.PUT);
      request.AddJsonBody(new
      {
        location = "global",
        properties = new
        {
          channelName = "FacebookChannel",
          properties = new
          {
            isEnabled = true,
            appId = facebookAppId,
            appSecret = facebookAppSecret
          }
        }
      });
      await _azureClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
```

where `_azureClient` is injected into my controller, something like this:

```
      azureRestClient.Authenticator = new MicrosoftAuthenticator(client, key, tenant, "https://management.azure.com");
      services.AddSingleton<IRestClient>(azureRestClient);
```